# How to install an updated version of PEAR / PHPUnit on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, php, pear

Most tutorials online show how to install PEAR by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

This installs version 1.6.1. It works great because it's super easy! My problem is that I want to install PHPUnit and it requires PEAR version 1.8.1 so my install of PHPUnit failed. So how do I install a newer version of PEAR on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

First, install PEAR.

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

Next, tell PEAR to update its own channel.

```
sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
```

Then, tell PEAR to upgrade itself to the newest version.

```
sudo pear upgrade-all
```

You should now have the newest version of PEAR installed.

To install PHPUnit, let PEAR know where to find PHPUnit.

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
```

Then install PHPUnit. (the -a makes sure all dependency packages are also installed)

```
sudo pear install -a phpunit/PHPUnit
```

**Update:**

According to the [latest PHPUnit installation documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html), you can install PHPUnit with the following commands (make sure you have updated PEAR first):

```
sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Comment: Incidentally it might be good to add `apt-get install curl` and `sudo pecl install xdebug` for code coverage

Comment: actually, I just discovered that `apt-get install php5-xdebug` is the easiest. =]

Comment: I've been burned a few times in the version difference between what is in the public repo and what's on pear, last time was earlier this year ( 2011 ) where there was a regression in the Ubuntu repo.

Answer (score 9):

Last versions of PhpUnit require ez/zeta components & symfony's YAML lib

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
sudo pear upgrade-all
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear install -a phpunit/PHPUnit
```

[See the last updated installation tutorial here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/)

Answer (score 3):

If installation using above command failed, You might need to install `Net_URL2-0.3.1` and then `HTTP_Request2-2.0.0RC1` before installation of PHPUnit on Ubuntu.
Find the latest version of the above packages and install them.

Example:

`sudo apt-get install curl`

`sudo pear install pear/Net_URL2-0.3.1`

`sudo pear install pear/HTTP_Request2-2.0.0RC1`

`sudo pear install -a phpunit/PHPUnit`