# Ubuntu 12.04 - Cannot install PEAR

Tags: ubuntu, pear

Following these instructions:

[How to install an updated version of PEAR / PHPUnit on Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/55055/how-to-install-an-updated-version-of-pear-phpunit-on-ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

I get `php-pear is already the newest version.`

then

```
sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
```

gives me

```
-bash: /usr/bin/pear: No such file or directory
```

Comment: try doing a `whereis pear` then use a full path with sudo

Comment: pear: /etc/pear . Then sudo etc/pear gives me /etc/pear command not found