# Setting up PEAR (excel) on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, pear

First off, I have **never** used Pear before, I'm a complete newbie, but I need to mix php and excel so... I ran

```
sudo apt-get install pear
```

and that went smoothly, but I can't get any further. I tried to install the Spreadsheet Excel Writer like this

```
sudo pear install Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.3
```

but was promptly told

> Failed to download pear/OLE within preferred state "stable", latest
>   release is version 1.0.0RC2, stability "beta", use
>   "channel://pear.php.net/OLE-1.0.0RC2" to install
>   pear/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer requires package "pear/OLE" (version >=
>   0.5) No valid packages found install failed

I upgraded it but it didn't change anything. I don't know how to get it to use a different channel and I can't find a way to install the package "pear/OLE". Please help! Thanks

Comment: Basically, the last version Ubuntu has in their repos is too old to use it, so you'll probably need to update the package by yourself. Please see this question, might give you tips on how to do it: http://superuser.com/questions/55055/how-to-install-an-updated-version-of-pear-phpunit-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have to install OLE-1.0.0RC2 `sudo pear install OLE-1.0.0RC2`

You can install Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer from scratch by

`git clone https://github.com/pear/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer.git`

`cd Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer`

`pear install package.xml`

More details [github](https://github.com/pear/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer)

Comment: thanks, I just tried it but I still get the same error

Comment: Did you install OLE-1.0.0RC2 `sudo pear install OLE-1.0.0RC2`

Comment: I hadn't, but now I have and I'm pretty sure that worked, thanks!

Comment: ok I edited my answer. Thanks for your reply :)