# How to fix Drush 8 / PHP 7.2 Warning "count(): Parameter must be an array..."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

I am running LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04.  I have a drupal 7 installation and I have installed drush 8.1.3 via Composer version 1.5.2. I believe there is bug in [php7.2 causing the error](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3226) as discussed on Github, however even after I applied the recommended fix which is to update the pear/console_table to the latest version [instructed here](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/php-console-table), the problem still remains. I also followed the instructions on [Super User](https://superuser.com) to be absolutely sure that I have [the most up to date version of pear](https://superuser.com/questions/55055/how-to-install-an-updated-version-of-pear-phpunit-on-ubuntu) installed as well (did not install PHPunit).  And, FYI in accordance with the [drush installation documentation found here](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/), I also made the proper changes to my `.bashrc` file as well (below).

Whenever I run `drush status` I receive the following error:

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                                 
PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini                     
PHP OS                 :  Linux                                        
Drush script           :  /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php 
Drush version          :  8.1.13                                       
Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                         
Drush configuration    :                                               
Drush alias files      :
```

If I execute `drush sql-connect`

```
Unable to load class Drush\Sql\Sql                                  [error]
Drush\Sql\SqlException: Unable to find a matching SQL Class. Drush   [error]
cannot find your database connection details. in
/home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc:541
Stack trace:
#0
/home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(221):
drush_sql_get_class()
#1 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422):
drush_sql_connect()
#2 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231):
_drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#3 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199):
drush_command()
#4
/home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67):
drush_dispatch(Array)
#5 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66):
Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#6 /home/webdevusr/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#7 {main}
```

The contents of my `~/.bashrc` file, are as follows:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

export PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH

# Include Drush bash customizations.
if [ -f "/home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.bashrc" ] ; then
source /home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.bashrc
fi

# Include Drush completion.

if [ -f "/home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.complete.sh" ] ; then
source /home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.complete.sh
fi

# Include Drush prompt customizations.

if [ -f "/home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.prompt.sh" ] ; then
source /home/webdevusr/.drush/drush.prompt.sh
fi
```

The result of `drush cc all` executed from within my drupal installation folder is:

```
No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.
```

Anyone know how to get drush to working for my local (LAMP) Drupal 7 installations?

Answer (score 2):

In the file *.config/composer/vendor/pear/console_table/Table.php*, we can see that the involved function `_updateRowsCols($rowdata = null)` has a wrong signature, its argument being assigned `null` as default - not *countable*.

Rather than using the `@` operator as it could mute more error/warning than intended, it is preferable to fix the function signature :

```
function _updateRowsCols($rowdata = []) {...}
```

... and/or to use the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) `??` to safely fallback to an empty (but countable) array right in the function call :

```
$this->_max_cols = max($this->_max_cols, count($rowdata ?? []));
```

---

[Edit] It's worth noting that the fix for this issue was committed to `pear/Console_Table` in October 2017 while the question was asked on 2018.. so just use the latest version... Anyway, just for information here is the code fix which use a ternary operator probably for backward compatibility :

```
function _updateRowsCols($rowdata = null)
    {
        // Update maximum columns.
        $this->_max_cols = max($this->_max_cols, is_array($rowdata) ? count($rowdata) : 0);

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit  .config/composer/vendor/pear/console_table/Table.php or look for that file first in your system. Open it with your favorite editor and in edit line 789. 
Silence it like this:

```
@$this->_max_cols = max($this->_max_cols, count($rowdata));
```

You're good to go.

Comment: I kept getting banned for asking Drupal related questions....that notably, other drupal users answered... so I decided to make life simple switch to Wordpress...  problem solved..